# "Can't open output file" error on scanf call

Tags: c, scanf, sublimetext3

I am trying to do a simple code in C using the text editor Sublime.
The problem is, when I try to use the *scanf* function I get an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("testing %d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file cccc.exe: Permission denied
>       collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: This just seems like a permission problem

Comment: Your code compile ok, a live test of it: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/b0nHamZUXjg1hFP4.   This is not a C question, it's your file permission problem.

Comment: try omitting the scan ...  `a = 42; //scanf("%d",&a);`

Comment: In general it is always a good idea to include your error/warning in text in the body of your question.

Comment: When I remove the "scan" it does works. So I guess we found the problem.
So I guess that Sublime doesnt allow to input varaibles

Comment: `scanf` gathers input from `stdin`; programs executing in Sublime's output panel have no `stdin` connected to them; thus they hang forever waiting for input that you cannot provide. You assume your code is broken and try to run it again, but the previous version is already running, which has the file locked, and the linker is unable to relink. Extremely common problem (but finding it on SO is very difficult). The answer to the question is to not run interactive programs directly within Sublime.

Comment: @Miguel, it's not about Sublime preventing use of "scanf". The problem (as several others have noted here) is that another copy of the program was running when you tried to compile the second time. Windows does not allow two processes to open the same file (in this case `cccc.exe`), so you can't create a new version of `cccc.exe` while it is running (and waiting for input, in your case).

Answer (score 1):

You may have another instance of g++ open in cmd. You may be running "a.exe" generated by g++ in Command Prompt. Due to the fact that a file already exits, and is being used, you can not create a file of same name.